# Fetch mysql with multiple values from single row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, filter

i have a filter functionality with `php` and `jquery/ajax` which my table with products looks like thist:

```
|id|status|name|colors_id|
-------------------
| 1|  1   | toy| 1,4,7   | <-- this are id`s of few filters, red,blue,etc...
```

My sql looks like that:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE status=1";
if(isset($_POST["color"])){
    $color_filter = implode(",", $_POST["color"]);
    $query .= "
     AND color_id IN(".implode(",", $_POST["color"]).")"; 
}
```

When i filter i put an `echo` on query and result is this

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = 1  AND color_id IN(1,4,7)
```

Bassically user check 3 colors and i want to go in database and fetch all rows which have `1,4,7` and display them.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="sidebar-widget color-widgets">
    <h6>FILTER BY COLOR </h6>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="common_selector color" id="white" value="1">
                  <label for="white">white</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="common_selector color" id="red" value="7">
                <label for="red">red</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" class="common_selector color" id="yellow" value="2">
                 <label for="yellow">yellow</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" class="common_selector color" id="blue" value="4">
                 <label for="blue">blue</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I if check 1,4 is getting me only the first in this case is 1 and doesnt find 4.
(I know about security is a project for learning ajax with mysql and php, next step is PDO)

Comment: Now you see why a proper database design does not include columns with comma delimited keys in

Comment: Do you can give me an advice for an alternative?thanks, i hope have a nice day.

Comment: you can create a new table "colors" that links your first table to each coolors_id, where each row has 3 columns: ID - IDfirstTable - idColor. in your example you would have 3 rows in this new table, one for each colors_id (1,4,7) like: row1: 1 - 1 -1, row2: 2 -1 -4, row3: 3 - 1 -7

Answer (score 0):

Hi (do not waste time to jquery)
not ajax but clear js fetch() and FormData for sending data and files

Sql see here:
https://pl.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP/Biblioteka_PDO

And sql injection prevent
https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/php-docs-7-en/pdostatement.execute.html

Regards

Learn from the best ;)

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC29ju8bIPH5as8OGnQzwJyA

Your table should looks:

```
toys:
id|status|name
1|1|Toy1
2|1|Toy2

toy_colors:
id|rf_toy_id|color_id
1|1|1
2|1|3
3|2|5
4|2|1

select * from toy_colors left join toys ON toy_colors.rf_toy_id =    toy.id where toy.status = 1
```

And with 3 tables color table (not tested)

```
colors:
id|name
1|Red
3|Gold
5|Silver

select * from toy_colors left join toys ON toy_colors.rf_toy_id =    toy.id LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = toy_colors.color_id where toy.status = 1
```

:)

Comment: I will try this method because i have already a table where i keep all colors when i save product.

Comment: Sample with color table

Comment: Is something wrong there, i tested your solution and is retriving me 2 products when i filter like this one: 'select * from toy_colors left join toys ON toy_colors.rf_toy_id =    toy.id where toy.status = 1 GROUP BY toy_colors.id AND toy_colors.id IN(4)' Is retriving me 2 products 1 have toy_colors id 4 and another one which doesnt have id 4... why is giving me 2 products, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the exact match as per color_id in your table or partial matching will also return row?

Better you create another table where color id will be saved linking main table. Something similar to below
main_table_id | color_id
11
1|2
1|3
2|2
2|3

etc.

Then you can use JOIN to retrieve your expected results.

Comment: exact match because one product can have multiple colors